# Stop Audio on Route Change in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-router

everyone. I'm still getting used to React and React Router, and this is one thing I have no figured out.

So, I have an app that plays a video (muted) and an audio track at the same time. I am using [React Player](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player) to play both. My view looks like this (VideoPlayer is the react-player tag):

```
<div>
    <VideoPlayer url={this.props.audio} playing={this.state.playing} />
    <VideoPlayer url={this.props.video} playing={this.state.playing} />
</div>
```

This setup has worked for me, and I am able to play and control them both via a common state. I can stop them via an event handler I hooked up to a button:

```
handleStop() {
    this.setState({playing: false})
}
```

And this works as well.

The issue, however, is that once I navigate to a different route, the audio (and presumably the video) remains playing in the background. Actually, let me rephrase, the audio **restarts** in the background when I change routes.

After reading [this page from the react-router docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md), I have tried to include logic to call `handleStop` in various lifecycle events, yet none of them does the trick. So far, I have tried putting calls to `handleStop` in `componentWillReceiveProps`, `componentWillUpdate`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount`.

The closest I got was putting the call in `componentWillUnmount`, but I always receive an error about setting the state of an unmounted component (which doesn't make sense either, if this is called *before* unmounting?).

So, by any chance, does anybody know where to put my call to handleStop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you triggering the navigation? If you're using a `<Link />`  Try manually changing routes so you can do stuff before you trigger it. [Navigation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/0.13.x/doc/06%20Mixins/Navigation.md)

Comment: Unfortunately, still doesn't work. The issue isn't that `handleStop` is never called, it's that after changing routes, the audio starts playing again. This bewilders me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this question is over 4 years old, but I had this problem today and wanted to share my way of solving it...

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import waves from '../audio/waves.mp3';
    
const RockyCoast = (props) => {
    // the audio variable needs to be stored in a ref in order to access it across renders
    let audio = useRef();
    // start the audio (using the .current property of the ref we just created) when the component mounts using the useEffect hook
    useEffect(() => {
        audio.current = new Audio(waves)
        audio.current.play()
    }, [])
    // Stop the audio when the component unmounts
    // (not exactly what you asked re React Router, but similar idea)
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            audio.current.pause()
            console.log("in cleanup")
        }
    }, [])
    ...

    return (
        <>
            ...
        </>
    )
}
export default RockyCoast;
```

Some of the key reasons this works properly is because we're declaring the `audio` variable as a React `ref`, so that we can access it again to pause it on unmount. It's also important that the dependency arrays for the two `useEffect` calls are the same (in my case they were empty, in order for them to act like `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`).

The question was asking specifically about changing routes using React Router, so there may be a little more work required for your specific circumstance, but if like me you have one parent component being rendered for the route where we need this feature, like this:

```
<Route exact path="/habitat/rocky_coast">
    <RockyCoast />
</Route>
```

(audio playing on the page, then stopping when we navigate to a different page), this solution works beautifully.

Hopefully this helps some other poor dev, who like me managed to create a project with a ton of audio clips playing over themselves lol!

Comment: Thank you so much for this... you are an absolute LEGEND! I was tripping up as I was trying to useState instead of useRef!

Comment: Lovely use of useRef :D

Comment: I have a timer component which needed to play an alarm on the parent and this is exactly what I needed thanks

Comment: it worked, thanks But can you explain it? Both useffects renders initially, How come that worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my own audio player I had created using useState when the user was in some exact views the audio continue to play, so I have solved this problem using [recoil](https://recoiljs.org/)  *Atoms* & *useRecoilState* and with [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/) *useLocation* & *useNavigate*

#### AudioAtom.js:

```
import { atom } from "recoil";

const playingAudioState = atom({
  key: "playingAudioState",
  default: false,
});

export default playingAudioState;
```

#### Player.jsx:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRecoilState } from "recoil";
import playingAudioState from "./AudioAtom";

function Player() {

const [audio, setAudio] = useState(new Audio(url));
const [playing, setPlaying] = useRecoilState(playingAudioState);

useEffect(() => {
  playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
}, [playing]);

...

return <>
...
</>

}
```

#### CustomRoutes.jsx:

```
import { useEffect} from "react";
import { useRecoilState } from "recoil";
import playingAudioState from "./AudioAtom";
import { ... , useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function CustomRoutes() {
const navigate = useNavigate();
const location = useLocation();

  const [playing, setPlaying] = useRecoilState(playingAudioState);

  const routesWithoutAudio = ["/", "/example", "/hello"];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (playing && routesWithoutAudio.includes(location.pathname)) {
      // if the audio is playing and the user is in a route with no audio we will set  
      // the state to false and refresh / reload de current page to not listen to it
      setPlaying(false);
      navigate(0 , { replace: true });
    }
  }, [location]);

return (
 ...Routes
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I never found an answer, even after moving the logic to push the URL into handleStop. So I just changed page using `window.location.href = '...'`. Hacky, but it worked.